# Allowing key-value pairs in Symfony 2 Bundle semantic configuration

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, bundle

Basically i'd like to allow an arbitrary (but **not empty**) number of **key-value pairs** in my configuration, under `billings` node, that is define an **associative array**.

I've this in my `Configurator.php` (part of):

```
->arrayNode('billings')
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->prototype('scalar')
    ->end()
->end()
```

And then, in my `config.yml`:

```
my_bundle:
    billings:
        monthly : Monthly
        bimonthly : Bimonthly
```

However, outputting `$config`:

```
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $processor     = new Processor();
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('my_bundle.billings', $config['billings']);

        var_dump($config);
        die();
    }

}
```

... what i get is **array index by numbers**, not an associative one:

```
 'billings' => 
     array (size=2)
         0 => string 'Monthly' (length=7)
         1 => string 'Bimonthly' (length=9)
```

Out of curiosity (and if this can help), i'm trying to inject this array as a service parameter (annotations from this great bundle: [JMSDiExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle)):

```
class BillingType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $billingChoices;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({"billingChoices" = @Inject("%billings%")})
     *
     * @param array $billingChoices
     */
    public function __construct(array $billingChoices)
    {
        $this->billingChoices = $billingChoices;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should add `useAttributeAsKey('name')` to your billing node configuration in `Configurator.php`.

More information about `useAttributeAsKey()` you can read at [Symfony API Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-node-options)

After changes billing node configuration it should be like:

```
->arrayNode('billings')
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
->end()
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm giving it a try and report back!

Comment: What if I want to avoid `isRequired` and provide a default array in case of null?

Comment: Am I correct that in `->useAttributeAsKey('name')` the `name` has special meaning or it's at least automatically added to the array?

Comment: What if you want to accept arrays also ? For example in my case
`
my_bundle:
    table:
        column:
            options: { "value": 1}
`

Answer (score 2):

You may add something like:

```
->arrayNode('billings')
    ->useAttributeAsKey('whatever')
    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
```

After that keys will magically appear.

See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12304

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to setup some nested arrays configuration.

Needs were

- A first level array with custom keys (discribing an entity path)
- Each of those arrays had to have one or more arbitrary tags as keys, with boolean value.

To achieve such a configuration, you have to casacade `prototype()` method.

So, the following configuration:

```
my_bundle:
    some_scalar: my_scalar_value
    first_level:
        "AppBundle:User":
            first_tag: false
        "AppBundle:Admin":
            second_tag: true
            third_tag: false
```

can be obtained using the following configuration:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');
$rootNode
    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet() # may or may not apply to your needs
    ->performNoDeepMerging() # may or may not apply to your needs
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('some_scalar')
            ->info("Some useful tips ..")
            ->defaultValue('default')
            ->end()
        ->arrayNode('first_level')
            ->info('Useful tips here..')
            # first_level expects its children to be arrays
            # with arbitrary key names
            ->prototype('array')
                # Those arrays are expected to hold one or more boolean entr(y|ies)
                # with arbitrary key names
                ->prototype('boolean')
                    ->defaultFalse()->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
return $treeBuilder;
```

Dumping $config from inside the extension class gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [some_scalar] => my_scalar_value
    [first_level] => Array
        (
            [AppBundle:User] => Array
                (
                    [first_tag] => 
                )

            [AppBundle:Admin] => Array
                (
                    [second_tag] => 1
                    [third_tag] => 
                )
        )
)
```

And voilà !

Answer (score 0):

This is what `useAttributeAsKey` actually does:

```
/**
 * Sets the attribute which value is to be used as key.
 *
 * This is useful when you have an indexed array that should be an
 * associative array. You can select an item from within the array
 * to be the key of the particular item. For example, if "id" is the
 * "key", then:
 *
 *     array(
 *         array('id' => 'my_name', 'foo' => 'bar'),
 *     );
 *
 *   becomes
 *
 *     array(
 *         'my_name' => array('foo' => 'bar'),
 *     );
 *
 * If you'd like "'id' => 'my_name'" to still be present in the resulting
 * array, then you can set the second argument of this method to false.
 *
 * This method is applicable to prototype nodes only.
 *
 * @param string $name          The name of the key
 * @param bool   $removeKeyItem Whether or not the key item should be removed
 *
 * @return ArrayNodeDefinition
 */
public function useAttributeAsKey($name, $removeKeyItem = true)
{
    $this->key = $name;
    $this->removeKeyItem = $removeKeyItem;

    return $this;
}
```